# Docker Selenium: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127

Tags: python, selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium's chromedriver in my python project.

I am building successfully my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:17.04
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome
FROM python:3.6
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get install -y libnss3 libgconf-2-4
ADD ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
ADD . /opt/example1/
# rights?
RUN chmod +x /opt/example1/assets/chromedriver
WORKDIR /opt/example1
CMD ["python","-u","program.py"]
```

But when I run my docker container I got following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "program.py", line 8, in
>   
>       MdCrawler(MD_START_URL, "MobileDe").start()   File "/opt/example1/mobile_de_crawler.py", line 17, in **init**
>       self.web_driver_chrome = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py",
>   line 73, in **init**
>       self.service.start()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
>   line 98, in start
>       self.assert_process_still_running()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
>   line 111, in assert_process_still_running
>       % (self.path, return_code) **selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service
>   /opt/example1/assets/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code
>   was: 127**

Anyone got an idea what could I do to prevent this error?
What is causing this crash?

Here is my initialization code where error occurs:

```
CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = os.path.abspath('assets/chromedriver')


class MdCrawler(Crawler):

def __init__(self, start_url, source):
    super().__init__(start_url, source)
    serialized_arr = self.read_data_from_json_file(JSON_FILE_PATH)
    self.sent_ids = [] if serialized_arr is None else serialized_arr
    >>> self.web_driver_chrome = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
    exit(1)
```

**Edit 1:**

I have edited Dockerfile (added ubuntu:17.04 and aptget libnss3 libgconf-2-4). After building my docker image, I got different error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
>   cannot find Chrome binary   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615279
>   (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5),platform=Linux
>   4.9.125-linuxkit x86_64)

**Edit 2:**

I have added

```
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
```

To my Dockerfile, but new error is coming:

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
>   Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally   (unknown error:
>   DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process started from
>   chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so
>   ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.45.615279
>   (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5),platform=Linux
>   4.9.125-linuxkit x86_64)

Comment: `docker run imagename /opt/example1/assets/chromedriver` might be informative; so far the error message you've shown just says that doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidMaze Here is my output: 

_(carcrawler) Lukas-MacBook-Pro-2:carcrawler lukadragicevic$ docker run lukatest /opt/example1/assets/chromedriver
/opt/example1/assets/chromedriver:_ 

error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @DavidMaze I have updated my post (see Edit 1). Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My minimal test script for Selenium chromedriver inside my Docker container looks like this:

```
import selenium.webdriver

options = selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://www.python.org/')
print(driver.title)
driver.close()
```

So it looks like you're missing `--headless` and `--no-sandbox` arguments.

Comment: I have exactly the same code now and it is running well, but I got the message from target website (mobile.de) "Unfortunately, automated access to this page was denied.". How could I pass this block?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an older question, I tried several fixes found across the various stackoverflow boards and none worked

Chrome driver requires additional libraries.  I was able to solve the issue with a single command on Linux:

`sudo apt-get install chromium-driver`

Many libraries and dependencies were all installed and finally the Chrome webdriver operated as expected within my code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you not forget to add *headless mode* ?

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
```

Comment: I forgot, now I have tested with this part of the code, but I faced same error.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

In my case I had an if/else statement in my code that was setting the `--headless` parameter based on an environment variable, but this env variable was not properly exported and was therefore not accessible within my (C#) program.

--> Consequently Chrome was started without --headless inside my docker container, causing the `DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist` error.

I now explicitly set this in the Dockerfile:
`ENV Selenium_UseHeadlessDriver=true`